# Camel context not starting in hello world app

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am attempting to run camel within spring. Below are the files i have..

1. POM xml file which have relevant dependencies.

> ```
> <properties>
>   <spring.version>3.2.11.RELEASE</spring.version>
>   <camel.version>2.14.1</camel.version>
> </properties>
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <dependencies>
>    <!-- camel core -->
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>       <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
>       <version>${camel.version}</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>       <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
>       <version>${camel.version}</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>       <artifactId>camel-metrics</artifactId>
>       <version>${camel-version}</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>    </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

2. Main context file (main-context.xml).

> ```
> <camel:camelContext trace="false" id="mc-service-camel-context" threadNamePattern="Camel (#camelId#) thread ##counter# - #name#">
> <camel:contextScan/>
> </camel:camelContext>
> ```

3. A route that looks like this

> ```
> @Component
> public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
>
> @Override
> public void configure() throws Exception {
>   from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=5000")
>   .log("Hello World!!")
>   .end();
> }
>
> }
> ```

4. And finally a main class that looks like this.

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
>
>   AbstractXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("main-context.xml");
> Thread.sleep(100000);
>
> }
> ```

Issue is i don't see the log "Hello World". Could someone give me some feedback on what i am missing..

Comment: Maybe you need to call `start` on the `appContext` instance in your main class.

Comment: I did call appContext.start(). Still doesn't work.

On a side note this code works <camelContext id="camel5" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"><routeBuilder ref="myRoute" /></camelContext><bean id="myRoute" class="com.mycompany.app.MyRoute"/> , so it seems the camel:contextScan isn't working..

Comment: You need to enable spring annotation processing or something so spring detects @Component beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable Component scanning.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app*" />
```